# Cannot rotate a table

Tags: rotating, sidewaystable

I am trying to rotate a table to fit it in a page but can't seem to make an example work with sidewaystable or sideways. Here is a simple code that I found online and should supposedly work fine but does not work for me. The table and caption both appear in horizontal orientation, and the table is pushed further down the page and away from the caption. Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Some description}% 
\label{tab:the_table}%      
\begin{sideways}%           
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
     Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
     Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sideways}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see it. However, here is a solution with `hvfloat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
  floatPos=!h,
  objectAngle=90,
  capPos=t,
  capVPos=t,
]{table}{%
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
    Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
    Text A                        &  Text B                       & Test C \\\hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{some description}{tab:the_table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't nest a `sideways` environment inside a `table*` environment. Depending on your typesetting objectives, you should either

- use a single `sidewaystable` environment, which will rotate the entire contents of the environment, including the caption, or
- use a `\rotatebox{90}{...}` directive to rotate just the `tabular` environment. Use `90` for a counterclockwise turn or `-90` for a clockwise turn.

Note that a `sidewaystable` environment always occupies an entire page.

Here's some sample code that illustrates both options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\begin{document}

%% First option: use a 'sidewaystable' env.
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\caption{Some description}
\label{tab:the_table}          
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

%% Second option: use a '\rotatebox{90){...}' directive
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Some description}
\label{tab:the_table}  
\rotatebox{90}{%        
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
 Text A & Text B & Test C \\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that dvi version doesn't show the rotated table but both alternatives (the version I posted and the one brought response) look fine when converted to pdf.